# Outlook add-in button on calendar overview

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

Is it possible to add a button to the command ribbon for the calendar overview in outlook. The [PrimaryCommandSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#extension-points-for-word-excel-powerpoint-and-onenote-add-in-commands) extensionpoint doesn't seem to be supported in Outlook add-ins. Adding a button to the appointment edit window isn't enough, because I need to perform an action for the whole calendar.

Comment: The only existing workaround for this scale, AFAIK, is to develop the add-in as a **COM add-in** until the Add-ins team decides to add the feature